# Is it possible to remove symbols from a shared library built with Android NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, debug-symbols, release-builds

I'm building a shared library for use in a Java app using the Android NDK. Using `readelf` to inspect the `lib/armeabi-v7a/libXXXlib.so` file generated by a release build, it appears to contain all the symbols (function, variable names) of my native C/C++ code.

Indeed, the shared object file appears to be identical for the debug and release builds. (The only difference in the output in the `libs` folder being whether or not the `gsb.setup` and `gdbserver` files are created.) I'm overriding the optimisation set by the NDK with an `APP_CFLAGS += -O3` in my `Application.mk`, but I wouldn't expect the release build to generate debug symbols by including the `-g` flag, which it does.

I found a comment on SO stating ['In both cases, debug and release, it leaves the -g flag in because, to quote the comment, "we generate symbol versions of the binaries that are later stripped when they are copied to the final project's libs/ directory"'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304670/changes-in-android-mk-not-changing-libs#comment14889467_11304760), and another stating: ['JNI cannot find the functions for java if they don't have names.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304670/changes-in-android-mk-not-changing-libs#comment14903472_11304760)

`ndk-build` is certainly stripping *something* from the `obj/armeabi-v7a/libXXXlib.so` file, as that is much larger than the one eventually created in `libs`, but it still seems to be leaving all my functions' and variables' names intact in the file.

Are *all* my functions' names required by JNI (rather than just the entry-points into the native code)?

If not, how can I remove the symbols which are not required?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Feel free to set default visibility=hidden, and set attribute visibility=default for the few functions you need to export (similar to DLLEXPORT) in Windows

Comment: Also, if you use explicit registration of JNI methods, you don't even need those to be visible.  See http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#native_libraries .

Comment: Thanks @alex-cohn, @fadden. I added `-fvisibility=hidden` to my `LOCAL_CFLAGS` in my `Android.mk` and it removed all the symbols *apart* from the JNI entry-points I'm exporting. (So I haven't set up explicit registration of JNI methods in JNI_OnLoad.) Do you know what's setting the visibility on those functions?

Comment: Also, do you know why this isn't set by default for release builds by ndk-build?

Comment: @fadden I did. Removing that removed them from the symbols. Thanks!