# Android ndk-build options to remove symbol table info

Tags: android, compilation, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Android ndk-build options : Is there any flag(s) or option(s) which can be set during build process in order to remove symbol table information from ".so" file ?

This question [Is it possible to remove symbols from a shared library built with Android NDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022983/is-it-possible-to-remove-symbols-from-a-shared-library-built-with-android-ndk) gives answer to change code but I need something like "strip" utility performs because I don't have source code with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NDK gives you the necessary tool. Choose the appropriate toolchain (e.g. arm GCC 4.8) and run (from command line)

```
$(NDK_ROOT)/toolchains/arm-linux-android-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-android-objcopy -N foo a.so
```

See *[How can I remove a symbol from a shared object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909528/how-can-i-remove-a-symbol-from-a-shared-object)* for more details.